# Object gets redrawn even after deletion

Tags: java, swing, repaint, paintcomponent

I need to clear my `JPanel`. This `JPanel` called `mainPane` has a `GridLayout` which contains `JScrollPane's, and these`JScrollPane`s contain custom`JPanel`s that override`paintComponent()`.

No matter what I try—setting the list to null, replacing the old instance with a new object—as soon as I resize the window frame, the view's `paintComponent()` get's called and it draws the views inside the `mainPane` again.

```
public void createContentPane() 
    {
        gridLay = new GridLayout(GRID_ROWS, GRID_COLUMNS);

        graphicViewList = new ArrayList<View>();
        for (int i = 0; i < graphicViewList.size(); i++) {
            View v = graphicViewList.get(i);
            v = null;
        }
        mainPane = new JPanel();

        clearGrid();
        mainPane.removeAll();
        mainPane.validate();
        graphicViewList.clear();
        imageModel.deleteObservers();
        mainPane.setLayout(gridLay);
        this.getContentPane().remove(mainPane);
        this.getContentPane().add(mainPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainPane.revalidate();
        mainPane.repaint();

    }

    public void createViews()
    {
        int idx = 0;
        graphicViewList.clear();

        while(idx < NUM_PERSPECTIVE) //iterator?
        {
            if(idx == 0)
            {
                graphicViewList.add(new ThumbnailView(this, imageModel));
                mainPane.add(new JScrollPane(graphicViewList.get(idx)));
                idx++;
                continue;
            }
            graphicViewList.add(new ImageView(this, imageModel));
            mainPane.add(new JScrollPane(graphicViewList.get(idx)));
            idx++;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < graphicViewList.size(); i++)
            graphicViewList.get(i).removeFocus();

        this.getContentPane().add(mainPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private void clearGrid()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < mainPane.getComponentCount(); i++) {
            JScrollPane sP =(JScrollPane) mainPane.getComponent(i);
            sP = null;

        }
    }
```

`createContentPane()` is overkill I know, I'm just desperate. So basically the first function and the second function get called in the GUI constructor. When I make a call to `createContentPane()` to replace the old UI (With the same structure, just different content), as soon as I resize the container, it's content are drawn anew. The only difference is that on the second `createContentPane()` call the resize draw draws over the layout and the elements aren't inside anymore.

I would think that `createContentPane()` would empty everything and removes all the references I might have, but `paintComponent()` still manage's to draw the scrollbars with the views.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

In clearGrid(), you need to call `remove(Component comp)` (in your case, sP) or `removeAll();`

Answer (score 2):

In your clearGrid method, you are not removing anything from the panel; you are just getting a reference to what's inside the mainPane and then setting that reference to null. Instead, you need to actually call `mainPane.remove(sP);` for each scroll pane.

Also, instead of that loop, you could try calling `mainPane.removeAll();`. Note, as mentioned in the documentation, you have to revalidate the panel afterwards.

[Container.removeAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#removeAll%28%29)

---

Here's that SSCCE that Andrew Thompson mentioned previously. Try doing this in the future when asking questions, so people can just run it and help fix it.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PanelClearerExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                PanelClearerExample app = new PanelClearerExample();
                app.startUp();
            }
        });
    }

    private final String CLEAR_COMMAND = "Clear";
    private final String REBUILD_COMMAND = "Rebuild";
    private JFrame controlFrame;
    private int displayCount = 0;
    private JFrame displayFrame;
    private JPanel displayPanel = new JPanel();

    private void startUp() {
        displayFrame = new JFrame("Display");
        displayFrame.setSize(300, 300);
        displayFrame.setLocation(300, 0);
        displayFrame.add(buildDisplay(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        controlFrame = new JFrame("Control");
        controlFrame.setSize(200, 100);
        controlFrame.add(buildControl(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        controlFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        displayFrame.setVisible(true);
        controlFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private Component buildDisplay() {
        populateDisplay();
        return displayPanel;
    }

    private void populateDisplay() {
        displayCount++;
        displayPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        String text = "Display " + displayCount;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            displayPanel.add(new JLabel(text, JLabel.CENTER));
        }
    }

    private Component buildControl() {
        JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        final JButton button = new JButton(CLEAR_COMMAND);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                if (CLEAR_COMMAND.equals(ae.getActionCommand())) {
                    clearDisplay();
                    button.setText(REBUILD_COMMAND);
                    button.setActionCommand(REBUILD_COMMAND);

                } else {
                    repopulateDisplay();
                    button.setText(CLEAR_COMMAND);
                    button.setActionCommand(CLEAR_COMMAND);
                }
            }
        });
        p.add(button);

        return p;
    }

    private void clearDisplay() {
        displayPanel.removeAll();
        displayPanel.repaint();
    }

    private void repopulateDisplay() {
        populateDisplay();
        displayPanel.revalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: I call mainPane.removeAll() a little lower? I'll try to call remove(sP) on each though.

Comment: What do you mean do you call it "a little lower"? I'm saying you can replace the loop inside that clearGrid method with a call to mainPane.removeAll();

Comment: I mean the call is already done a few lines lower in this method. The loop was added as a last minute check in to see if anything at all would work, initially removeAll was the only method called in this method.

Comment: The documentation says that you should revalidate or repaint afterwards. I added an SSCCE to the response.